# Spring Boot 2.3.1 Duplicate Bean Definitions

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am upgrading from Spring Boot 1.5.x to 2.3.1.

Encountered the following Bug which fixed in Spring boot earlier.
https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1448

Tried the following property workaround ,this is not helping as well.

> spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true

Anyone facing the same issue or any workaround?

> Error Below

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionOverrideException: Invalid bean definition with name 'org.springframework.context.config.internalBeanConfigurerAspect' defined in org.springframework.context.annotation.aspectj.SpringConfiguredConfiguration: Cannot register bean definition [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=null; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.context.annotation.aspectj.SpringConfiguredConfiguration; factoryMethodName=beanConfigurerAspect; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in org.springframework.context.annotation.aspectj.SpringConfiguredConfiguration] for bean 'org.springframework.context.config.internalBeanConfigurerAspect': There is already [Root bean: class [org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=null; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=aspectOf; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] bound.
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.registerBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:941) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:286) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:144) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:120) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:236) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:280) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:96) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:707) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:533) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
at XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.main(XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.java:38) [classes/:
```

**

> UPDATE

**

Setting the AllowBeanDefinitionOverriding programmatically help to resolve this part (earlier was trying to inject via property file),
But keeping the this thread open as the original rootcause is in spring-jpa,spring-beans is not obvious yet.

```
   SpringApplication sa = new SpringApplication(xxxxxxx.class);
   sa.setAllowBeanDefinitionOverriding(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

We were facing similar issue as OP - once upgraded from spring boot 2.2.8 to 2.3.1 the junit tests around auto configuration started failing with BeanDefinitionOverrideException error and the solution mentioned by OP did not work. Setting the property spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true via properties file or via environment post processor didn't work as well.

**Fix:**

We were using ApplicationContextRunner to test loading multiple beans in the context. Calling the method withAllowBeanDefinitionOverriding(true) from instance of ApplicationContextRunner fixed it.

According to Spring Boot 2.3.0 release notes [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.3-Release-Notes)

> "For consistency with SpringApplication, ApplicationContextRunner now
> disables bean overriding by default. If you need to use bean
> overriding for a test, withAllowBeanDefinitionOverriding can be used
> to enable it."